# Complete website duplication with EE v2.9.2 and MSM v2.1.7?

Tags: ee2, multi-site-manager

Am I able to **safely** duplicate an **entire** website (ie; with entries) with the above versions of EE & MSM?

[The documentation](https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/cp/sites/createsite.html) seems to say ‘yes’! But I’ve read that there were problems and so the functionality was discontinued in v3.0.

I’m a bit nervous for 2 reasons:

1.) Due to the crazy timeline, we’re thinking of doing it directly on the production/live server (eeek).

2.) It’s a reasonably large website (30+pages, 100’s of videos). So my cost estimate would be wildly different if I had to copy all the content entries manually.

Has anyone had any experience with this? Any advice would be welcome.

Cheers,

CJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works OK, but doesn't include all your core plugins, like matrix, playa, taxonomy etc.

So your going to be doing a fair bit of manual labour